# iOS - CS193p - Floating point numbers feature in calculator tutorial not working

Tags: ios

I've been working on learning iOS development and followed the Stanford video tutorials (CS193p) and assignment (to be precise the 1st assignment). Essentially I've been able complete the building of basic functionality of the calculator + some advanced features but I've been unable to compile floating point numbers i.e. when I type 5.9 it ignores the "5." and it processes the 9 as the number. What could be the reason? I've made sure I linked my dot button to the digitPressed option in the file's owner.

My code for the digitPressed action is as below

```
    -(IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *digit = [[sender titleLabel] text];
    NSRange range = [[display text] rangeOfString:@"."];
    if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) 
    {
        if ( ! ([digit isEqual:@"."] && (range.location != NSNotFound))) {
            [display setText:[[display text] stringByAppendingFormat:digit]];
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if ([digit isEqual:@"."]) {
            [display setText: @"0."];
        }
        else {
            [display setText: digit];
        }

        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = YES;

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber` is being set to NO after "." is tapped.